# Refactoring overuse of jQuery show/hide methods for simple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented some buttons on a web page that show and hide some text based on which button the user clicks:

Please bear in mind that the `.reveal-1` fragment is set to `display:none` in the CSS by default.

http://bestclownintown.co.uk/ct/bootstrap-3.3.7/docs/examples/CT_task/index.html

HTML:

```
  <div class="media">
     <div class="media-left"> <a href="#"> <img alt="New delivery options" class="media-object" src="images/thumbnail-new-delivery-options.jpg"> </a> </div>
     <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">Cotton Traders Introduces New Delivery Options</h4>
        <p class="text-muted">14th January 2016</p>
        <p>Cheshire based retailer, Cotton Traders, has added three new delivery options to its e-commerce offering, in order to improve the customer shopping experience.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-default reveal-button-1" href="#" role="button">Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <div class="reveal-1">
          <p>The casual clothing retailer now offers its UK customers a choice of standard, next day, Sunday and nominated delivery options.</p>
          <p>With more delivery options to choose from, customers will benefit from this added convenience, allowing them to get their items quicker and at a time that suits them, for as little as £3.99.</p>
          <p>Talking about the introduction, Supply Chain Director, Caroline Allerton, said: "As a company we are constantly striving to improve the offering for our customers and this includes the delivery options.</p>
          <p>"We know that our customers all have busy lives, so the introduction of these options will fit into their schedule and allow them to get their orders when they need them."</p>
          <p>The introduction comes after Cotton Traders launched its dedicated Australian e-commerce website earlier this year.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-default hide-button-1" href="#" role="button">Read Less <i class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
 $(".reveal-button-1").click(function(){
      $(".reveal-1").show();
  });

  $(".reveal-button-1").click(function(){
      $(".reveal-button-1").hide();
  });

  $(".reveal-button-1").click(function(){
      $(".hide-button-1").show();
  });

  $(".hide-button-1").click(function(){
      $(".reveal-1").hide();
  });

  $(".hide-button-1").click(function(){
      $(".hide-button-1").hide();
  });

  $(".hide-button-1").click(function(){
      $(".reveal-button-1").show();
  });
```

1) So in the first call to the jQuery object we show the `<div>` with a class of `.reveal-1` when `.reveal-button-1` is clicked

2) Then we hide `.reveal-button-1`

3) We then show `.hide-button-1` when `.reveal-button-1` is clicked

Now the hide button is present in the DOM.

4) We hide the `<div>` with a class of `.reveal-1` when `.hide-button-1` is clicked

5) We hide `.hide-button-1`

6) Finally we show `.reveal-button-1` again.

Are there any solutions I can apply to refactor my JavaScript, so that I am not calling to the jQuery object as often and repeating myself so many times. I am aware of the `.toggle` method but I am not sure that it can be applied in this case. Please give a thorough explanation with your answer as I need to understand the jQuery logic. I have tried to keep the jQuery logic as simple as possible as I am only of a junior level.

I currently have 24 lines of jQuery code for 4 HTML fragements which seems quite excessive, but I don't know if there is a better way to implement/optimise.

Comment: why are you having several events for the same object (ex: $(".reveal-button-1").click). You could have 1 event and put all the actions inside of it

Answer (score 1):

here it is,
On any button click all element toggles visibility. its exactly what you need.

```
$(".reveal-button-1, .hide-button-1").click(function(){ //on click of either button.
  $(".reveal-1, .reveal-button-1, .hide-button-1").toggle(); //toggle visibilty on all the corresponding elements
});
```

Make sure your initial values (display:none) are correct.

reveal button click will hide itself, show the hide button and toggle the reveal field (to show).

since the hidden button is now visible and the reveal button is no longer. once we click on this button the field will toggle (to be hidden again). the reveal button will be visible again.

side note: You probably want to use better css classes in your html though. (to make a more generic javascript code so that you can re-use its functionality).

## re-usable solution

here is a re-usable version, with better classes.

```js
$('.toggle-btn').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.container').find('.toggle').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="toggle-btn toggle" style="display:none;">show</div>
  <div class="toggle-btn toggle">hide</div>
  <div class="toggle">bla bla</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="toggle-btn toggle" style="display:none;">show</div>
  <div class="toggle-btn toggle">hide</div>
  <div class="toggle">bla bla</div>
</div>
```

Explanation: when a toggle-button is clicked. it goes and finds the first parent that has a class .container. then from this parent, it checks all the html elements with the .toggle class inside this container and toggles their visibility.

Side note on this solution: it is not a very prerformant solution because every time it tries to find the container class in its parents and then tries to find all the childs with class toggle. (better is to cache these classes). but for this simple solution it doesn't really matter.

### out of the box libraries

- [bootstrap collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)
- [jquery accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: My plan is to extend this to the 4 fragments I have .reveal-1 .reveal-2 etc. In which this code block will need to be repeated I believe, as to break the web page up into specific areas that can be shown/hidden.

Comment: than you should wrap it inside a container. and how should reveal 2 work? should it hide reveal 1 field as well. this makes your question ambigious

Comment: What is it exactly what you want to make? you want to make like tabs that open and close fields or do you more want to make a hide and show button that hide and show individual containers?

Comment: I hope this gives you enough material to work on. its always best to break down your solutions into small bits and try and make simplest as possible solution.

Comment: Yes thank you for such an exhaustive answer, to answer your question I want to make exactly what I have in the example above. Only 1 HTML fragment should be open closed by the corresponding show/hide buttons (which I have working). To make this work across the 4 fragments I have though, I believe the first code block you have supplied must be repeated 4 times, with each block referencing elements referencing the HTML classes 1, 2 3 and 4. (Hope this makes sense)

Comment: You can use my solution: + In the click method figure out which container is open and run the click method on the hide button. But better: look at the OOTB links I pasted.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one event handler for each element. Repeating like that causes a lot of extra functions to be called on each event, which will slow your site down. (Probably not noticeably, but if your site grows it could become problematic.)

If your HTML is structured similarly for each of your sections, you could eliminate the specific classes, and go on a more general approach. (Shortened for brevity.)

```
<a class="... reveal-button"...>
<div class="reveal">
    ...
    <a class="... hide-button"...>
</div>
```

Then down inside your JavaScript, instead of 4 sets of all your calls, you can do just a single. I'll explain how this works as we go. The function [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the preferred method to wire events since jQuery 1.7.

```
$('.reveal-button').on('click', function () { 
    var $self = $(this); // 'this' will be the element that was clicked.
    $self.next('div.reveal')
         .show();
    $self.hide();
});

$('.hide-button').on('click', function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parent(); // refers to div.reveal
    $parent.hide(); // hide the div
    $parent.prev('a.reveal-button').show(); // show the reveal button.
});
```